# Like a public facebook post using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-php-sdk

I am able to **like** a **public facebook post** made by my friend using graph api as long as we are friends on facebook. I unfriended him and then tried the same thing but it wouldn't work.

**Permissions obtained : publish_stream,read_stream,publish_actions,read_mailbox**

To like the post I used **"POST /POST_ID/likes?access_token=SECRECTACCESSTOKEN"**

I use apigee.com to test .

Is it not possible to like a public status or post using graph api ?

I did try to like the post as a normal user through facebook. It worked fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance ! :)

The response I get when I'm friends with the user :
**True**

The response I get when I'm not friends with the user :

**{
  "error":  {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200
  }**
}

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to like public posts on Facebook using the API. However, if you friend has restricted privacy settings, the public may not be able to comment / like their posts.

A good giveaway is if you are able to see the post, but can only Share it - the Like and Comment actions are hidden:

[image: Like and Comment actions hidden on public posts]

See if your friend has restricted privacy options, preventing you from Liking / Commenting on their posts. Then retest your API call on a different public post which allows Liking / Commenting.

---

**Edit**

Also, make sure you are calling the API correctly:

`POST https://graph.facebook.com/{object_id}/likes`

The Object ID can be obtained from the API, and is usually the last part (after the underscore) of the actual ID: `1234567890_009988776655`, i.e. `009988776655` is the actual object ID.

Comment: I'm sure its not my friends restricted privacy settings because I am able to like it normally even when we are not friends .

Comment: I'm able to like facebook posts made by my friends and pages. So I think I am calling the API correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Graph API Explorer".

Since you receive "Permission Error". Try to double check permission list.

This method is right. But used to likes an object.

```
POST /[POST_ID]/likes?access_token=SECRECTACCESSTOKEN
```

For Posting a public status:

```
POST /[USER_ID]/feed?access_token=SECRECTACCESSTOKEN&message=HELLO
```

If you're running Unix, try to use this:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes

curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]/feed
```

Comment: I'm sure I have the required permissions.I used the debugger to check. 
I don't want to post a public status,I want to like a public status.